# Springboot app calling a thirdparty API does not provide the API's 400 Exception JsonResponse, but Postman show the Response, how can I fix it?

Tags: rest, api, spring-boot

In my Springboot App, my local API calls a Thridparty API, format the response and send to the UI.
At a particular usecase I am geting a 400 Exception with a JSON response by calling third party Api directly in Postman which is good, but In my app, when I catch the exception all I see is a 400 Bad Request and I dont get the JSON response.

Exception handling for HttpClientException to get the JsonResponse

Comment: I think this should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26676405/how-to-parse-the-response-body-in-java-when-the-http-request-has-return-status.  ?

Comment: Thank You @Rob Scully!!. that worked